# Is it possible to intercept methods of a Executor Service that is initialised in a specific java class using bytebuddy

Tags: java, bytecode, byte-buddy

Using byte buddy, I am trying to intercept the method of executor service that is initialised in a known class. The following is a sample code.

```
public class TestClient {

    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

    public Response get() {
        Future<Response> future = executorService.submit(this::call2);
        return future.get();
    }
}
```

The following intercepts all usage of ExecutoreService, including those in dependencies as well, which I want to avoid.

```
return ElementMatchers.isSubTypeOf(ExecutorService.class);
```

Is there a way to intercept the method of executor service initialised in any class of a specific package or class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Byte Buddy can only alter byte code. If you could not implement it in Java, Byte Buddy is unlikely able to help.

What you can do is to alter all constructors creating a different target object. In this object, override the relevant methods.

To change constructors, have a look at MemberSubstitution.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.

So you mean to say there is no way to ignore an instance of ExecutorService based on which class it is initialized?

What I am trying to achieve is to narrow the scope of ElementMatcher to a specific instance that is created inside my application a not in some dependent library like spring or drop wizard. The constructor approach appears to be tedious.

Comment: @AvinashVundyala a matcher for code patterns can only match code patterns. However, you can inject code containing a runtime check into all occurrences. The injected code would have to check the caller, e.g. via `StackWalker`, and branch to the original code if the caller is not supposed to be altered.